# Obtaining current value in registers/cache?

Tags: c++, caching, assembly, cpu, cpu-registers

Is there any way (in ASM/C/C++) to be able to query the contents of memory addresses in the cache or even get the current values in registers?

Would this be like Heisenberg principle in effect? The code trying to retrieve the value from the register could cause the register to be unloaded?

Comment: Any particular CPU you are interested in?

Comment: The Heisenberg principle definitely applies to the cache as well as whatever registers `printf()` and family uses. But other than that, you can try to slap on a debugger and break the program.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I didn't have a specific CPU in mind. Relatively modern. Nehalem+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard instructions in most processors to "read value from the cache". One can surmise that modern processors are able to read/write cache content for testing purposes, but if there are such instructions, they aren't publicly described, and probably require care when using them to avoid interfering with the actual code executing. Reading any memory will potentially affect what is in the cache-line that you want to inspect.

Register values requires fairly careful attention to how you write code, and it's usually almost impossible to store ALL the register values without affecting SOMETHING somewhere, although you can get pretty close in most processors by using a "push" type  instruction to store values on the stack. Once the values are "saved", they can be fetched using regulare memory read instructions, and since the values are already stored away, you can use (almost) any register for the rest of the code.

Edit: Since the processor type is now specified: 
On x86 processors in 32-bit mode, one can use `PUSHA` to push all registers onto the stack (including the ORIGINAL value of ESP in the middle of the list). However, for x86-64, you have to use the individual PUSH instructions for each register. But it is still feasible to do that.

I'm not familiar with any instructions from Intel to inspect cache-contents.